# Get crash on didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm sending notification when user is offline, its chatting app.

I recieve message on `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, and i fire notification in it

```
   NSMutableDictionary *foo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [foo setObject:strBadgeNumber forKey:kBadgeNumber];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNoti_BadgeNumber object:nil userInfo:foo];
```

and i get notification on `viewcontroller`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setView:) name:kNoti_BadgeNumber object:nil];
```

but i get crash on `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method, here is error :

```
2016-08-12 12:31:59.246 [4788:1586454] -[NSConcreteNotification _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ea1a10
2016-08-12 12:31:59.247 [4788:1586454] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ea1a10'
```

What's wrong in this ?

Comment: Can you show the code of `setView` function?

Comment: it' blank.. just nslog there